# Is there a way to disable the .highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis || highcharts-axis-resizer duplicate behaviour?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, custom-directive, jstockchart

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ASjN.png)

On dragging the Y-axis(highcharts-axis-resizer) to change the aspect ratio of the graphs, sometimes a duplicate axis (even multiple) of the same group and the classs is generated and is non functional which persists even on changing the behaviour.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle, codesandbox?

Comment: Not getting the same issue on jsfiddle.

Comment: So, maybe you can send me a package with the project and instructions on how to run it?